# Facing issue with filtering objects inside array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search

I have below the object.

```
{
categories: [
  {
    "category": {
      "categoryName": "categoryName1"
    },
    "newsletter": [
      {
        "name": "AAA",
        "description": "111"
      },
      {
        "name": "BBB",
        "description": "222"
      },
      {
        "name": "CCC",
        "description": "333"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": {
      "categoryName": "categoryName2"
    },
    "newsletter": [
      {
        "name": "DDD",
        "description": "444"
      },
      {
        "name": "EEE",
        "description": "555"
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

I'm trying to perform search operation between the category, name, and description.

I have below the logic.

```
this.selectedCategoryData = this.categorisedData.filter((item) => {
    const categoryMatch = item.category.categoryName.toLowerCase().includes(filterValueLowercase);
    const newslettersMatch = item.newsletters.some(newsletter =>
        return newsletter.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValueLowercase) ||
    newsletter.description.toLowerCase().includes(filterValueLowercase);
    );
    return categoryMatch || newslettersMatch;
});
```

This is my current logic. But it's working with some, not OR. Currently, it returns the whole subarray when found anything. If the value is found in the sub-array, it returns the whole array.
How can I filter with subArray and assign the value?

Expected output like below:

**First Scenario**

```
filterValue = "AAA" //returns the below object
categories: [
  {
    "category": {
      "categoryName": "categoryName1"
    }
    "newsletter": [
      {
        "name": "AAA",
        "description": "111"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

**Second Scenario:**

```
filterValue = "categoryName1" //returns the below object
categories: [
  {
    "category": {
      "categoryName": "categoryName1"
    }
    "newsletter": [
      {
        "name": "AAA",
        "description": "111"
      },
      {
        "name": "BBB",
        "description": "222"
      },
      {
        "name": "CCC",
        "description": "333"
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: I've downvoted because it's basically a "write the code for me" question. The code in the question suggests that you know how to achieve it. You can e.g. first filter the categories and then the newsletters if the value isn't the category name.

Comment: Have you noticed your data is invalid? You're missing a comma in `} "newsl`

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan Thank you for your reply. I edit my data just missing the ",".

Comment: @jabaa Thank you for your reply. I know we can not ask code here. But I am facing truble to how can we peform search inside array object. I mentioned my code. I never ask directly code without trying.

Comment: In that case you should reduce and isolate the actual problem. You apparently know how to search. That doesn't seem to be the actual problem here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Use `Array::reduce()` to compose the result array
2. Use case-insensitive `RegExp` for search the string

```js
const result = items.reduce((regex => (r, item) => {

  if(regex.test(item.category.categoryName)){ // category match - reuse the item
    r.push(item);
  }else{ // check news letters
    const newsletter = item.newsletter.filter(e => regex.test(e.name) || regex.test(e.description));
    if(newsletter.length){
      r.push({...item, newsletter});
    }
  }
  return r;
})(new RegExp('aaa', 'i')), []);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
const items = [
  {
    "category": {
      "categoryName": "categoryName1"
    },
    "newsletter": [
      {
        "name": "AAA",
        "description": "111"
      },
      {
        "name": "BBB",
        "description": "222"
      },
      {
        "name": "CCC",
        "description": "333"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": {
      "categoryName": "categoryName2"
    },
    "newsletter": [
      {
        "name": "DDD",
        "description": "444"
      },
      {
        "name": "EEE",
        "description": "555"
      }
    ]
  }
];
</script>
```